# Testing different types of regressions

Tags: r, regression

I've tryed linear, quadratic and cubic regression, but my p value is constantly under 0,7, there is a way o test multiple types of regressions? I need hese for my thesys. I can't give more datas

[[image]]

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have tried several types of regressions and want to test more? Looking at your graph, try package [segmented](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html).

Comment: Notice that p-value is calculated from t-value which is calculated from betas and standard errors. Standard error depends on standard deviation (variance) and sample size. You either have to decrease the variation or increase the sample size.

Comment: If you use a polynomial of size $N-1$ then you will get a $p$-value of 1. And enough over-fitting for it to be useless. You shouldn't aim for results based on $p$-values - does the fit explain what you see?